# Validation of registration form with AJAX and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, validation

I have a Username field in my registration form. When the user hits the Submit button, it should check if the username is not empty and that such username doesn't exist yet. So I have these functions:

```
function register() {
    var userName = checkIsUsernameExist();
    var passwordMatch = checkPasswordMatch();
    if(userName && passwordMatch){
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php",
        {
            command : "register",
            username : $("#txtNewUsername").attr("value"),
            password : $("#txtNewPassword").attr("value"),
            email : $("#txtEmail").attr("value"),
            phone : $("#txtPhone").attr("value")
        },
        function ()
        {
            $("#divIsRegFormValid").removeClass("registrationFormAlert");
            $("#divIsRegFormValid").addClass("registrationFormConfirm");
            $("#divIsRegFormValid").html("Thank you for registering!");
        }
    );
    } else {
        $("#divIsRegFormValid").removeClass("registrationFormConfirm");
        $("#divIsRegFormValid").addClass("registrationFormAlert");
        $("#divIsRegFormValid").html("Some errors occured. Please register again.");
    }
}



function checkIsUsernameExist(){
    if($("#txtNewUsername").attr("value") == "") {
        $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("");
        return false;
    } else {
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php", 
        {
            command : 'isUsernameExist',
            username : $("#txtNewUsername").attr("value")
        }).done(
        function(result)
        {
            if (result != true){
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").removeClass("registrationFormAlert");
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").addClass("registrationFormConfirm");
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is available!");
                return true;
            } else {
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").removeClass("registrationFormConfirm");
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").addClass("registrationFormAlert");
                $("#divIsUsernameExist").html("This username is not available!");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At this moment I only receive False if the username is empty, and if it's not - I get Undefined (checked it with some Alert commands). So how can I make it work and return True or False if the username is entered and it's been checked if such username already exist or not?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

.val() is prefered `$("#txtEmail").attr("value") =>  $("#txtEmail").val()` ;)

Comment: No, that's not it. I explained it in my response to slash197 just above.

Answer (score 0):

You get undefined probably because there is no value attribute in your html use `$('#txtEmail').val()` instead.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it. I've been told that I should use synchronous AJAX here, I tried to search it, but everything I tried so far didn't give me any result, I still get "undefined".